# Check server status on Twisted

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, autobahn

While I was writing simple message-based fileserver and client, I got the idea about checking fileserver status, but don't know how to realize this: just try to connect and disconnect from server (and how disconnect immediately, when server is not running, if using this way?) or maybe twisted/autobahn have some things, which help to get server status without creating "full connection"?

a) fileserver.py

```
import os
import sys
import json

from twisted.internet import reactor
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory, WebSocketServerProtocol, listenWS

CONFIG_TEMPLATE = ''
CONFIG_DATA = {}

class MessageBasedServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    """
Message-based WebSockets server
Template contains some parts as string:
[USER_ID:OPERATION_NAME:FILE_ID] - 15 symbols for USER_ID,
10 symbols for OPERATION_NAME,
25 symbols for FILE_ID
other - some data
"""
    def __init__(self):
        path = CONFIG_DATA['path']
        base_dir = CONFIG_DATA['base_dir']
        # prepare to working with files...
        if os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isdir(path):
            os.chdir(path)
            if not os.path.exists(base_dir) or not os.path.isdir(base_dir):
                os.mkdir(base_dir)
                os.chdir(base_dir)
        else:
            os.makedir(path)
            os.chdir(path)
            os.mkdir(base_dir)
            os.chdir(base_dir)
        # init some things
        self.fullpath = path + '/' + base_dir

    def __checkUserCatalog(self, user_id):
        # prepare to working with files...
        os.chdir(self.fullpath)
        if not os.path.exists(user_id) or not os.path.isdir(user_id):
            os.mkdir(user_id)
            os.chdir(user_id)
        else:
            os.chdir(self.fullpath + '/' + user_id)

    def onOpen(self):
        print "[USER] User with %s connected" % (self.transport.getPeer())

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print '[USER] Lost connection from %s' % (self.transport.getPeer())

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        """
Processing request from user and send response
"""
        user_id, cmd, file_id = payload[:54].replace('[', '').replace(']','').split(':')
        data = payload[54:]
        operation = "UNK" # WRT - Write, REA -> Read, DEL -> Delete, UNK -> Unknown
        status = "C" # C -> Complete, E -> Error in operation
        commentary = 'Succesfull!'
        # write file into user storage
        if cmd == 'WRITE_FILE':
            self.__checkUserCatalog(user_id)
            operation = "WRT"
            try:
                f = open(file_id, "wb")
                f.write(data)
            except IOError, argument:
                status = "E"
                commentary = argument
            except Exception, argument:
                status = "E"
                commentary = argument
                raise Exception(argument)
            finally:
                f.close()
        # read some file
        elif cmd == 'READU_FILE':
            self.__checkUserCatalog(user_id)
            operation = "REA"
            try:
                f = open(file_id, "rb")
                commentary = f.read()
            except IOError, argument:
                status = "E"
                commentary = argument
            except Exception, argument:
                status = "E"
                commentary = argument
                raise Exception(argument)
            finally:
                f.close()
        # delete file from storage (and in main server, in parallel delete from DB)
        elif cmd == 'DELET_FILE':
            self.__checkUserCatalog(user_id)
            operation = "DEL"
            try:
                os.remove(file_id)
            except IOError, argument:
                status = "E"
                commentary = argument
            except Exception, argument:
                status = "E"
                commentary = argument
                raise Exception(argument)
        self.sendMessage('[%s][%s]%s' % (operation, status, commentary), isBinary=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print "using python fileserver_client.py [PATH_TO_config.json_FILE]"
    else:
        # read config file
        CONFIG_TEMPLATE = sys.argv[1]
        with open(CONFIG_TEMPLATE, "r") as f:
            CONFIG_DATA = json.load(f)
        # create server
        factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://localhost:9000")
        factory.protocol = MessageBasedServerProtocol
        listenWS(factory)
        reactor.run()
```

b) client.py

```
import json
import sys
import commands

from twisted.internet import reactor
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory, WebSocketClientProtocol, connectWS

CONFIG_TEMPLATE = ''
CONFIG_DATA = {}


class MessageBasedClientProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):
    """
Message-based WebSockets client
Template contains some parts as string:
[USER_ID:OPERATION_NAME:FILE_ID] - 15 symbols for USER_ID,
10 symbols for OPERATION_NAME,
25 symbols for FILE_ID
other - some data
"""
    def onOpen(self):
        user_id = CONFIG_DATA['user']
        operation_name = CONFIG_DATA['cmd']
        file_id = CONFIG_DATA['file_id']
        src_file = CONFIG_DATA['src_file']
        data = '[' + str(user_id) + ':' + str(operation_name) + ':' + str(file_id) + ']'
        if operation_name == 'WRITE_FILE':
            with open(src_file, "r") as f:
                info = f.read()
            data += str(info)
        self.sendMessage(data, isBinary=True)

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        cmd = payload[1:4]
        result_cmd = payload[6]
        if cmd in ('WRT', 'DEL'):
            print payload
        elif cmd == 'REA':
            if result_cmd == 'C':
                try:
                    data = payload[8:]
                    f = open(CONFIG_DATA['src_file'], "wb")
                    f.write(data)
                except IOError, e:
                    print e
                except Exception, e:
                    raise Exception(e)
                finally:
                    print payload[:8] + "Successfully!"
                    f.close()
            else:
                print payload
        reactor.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print "using python fileserver_client.py [PATH_TO_config.json_FILE]"
    else:
        # read config file
        CONFIG_TEMPLATE = sys.argv[1]
        with open(CONFIG_TEMPLATE, "r") as f:
            CONFIG_DATA = json.load(f)
        # connection to server
        factory = WebSocketClientFactory("ws://localhost:9000")
        factory.protocol = MessageBasedClientProtocol
        connectWS(factory)
        reactor.run()
```

Comment: Why would you want to check the connection, what does that achieve? Just connect when you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find solution this issue: using callLater or deferLater for disconnect from server, if can't connect, but when all was 'OK', just take server status, which he says.

```
import sys

from twisted.internet.task import deferLater
from twisted.internet import reactor
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory, WebSocketClientProtocol, connectWS

CONFIG_IP = ''
CONFIG_PORT = 9000


def isOffline(status):
    print status


class StatusCheckerProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):

    def __init__(self):
        self.operation_name = "STATUS_SRV"
        self.user_id = 'u00000000000000'
        self.file_id = "000000000000000000000.log"

    def onOpen(self):
        data = '[' + str(self.user_id) + ':' + str(self.operation_name) + ':' + str(self.file_id) + ']'
        self.sendMessage(data, isBinary=True)

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        cmd = payload[1:4]
        result_cmd = payload[6]
        data = payload[8:]
        print data
        reactor.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print "using python statuschecker.py [IP] [PORT]"
    else:
        # read preferences
        CONFIG_IP = sys.argv[1]
        CONFIG_PORT = int(sys.argv[2])
        server_addr = "ws://%s:%d" % (CONFIG_IP, CONFIG_PORT)
        # connection to server
        factory = WebSocketClientFactory(server_addr)
        factory.protocol = StatusCheckerProtocol
        connectWS(factory)
        # create special Deffered, which disconnect us from some server, if can't connect within 3 seconds
        d = deferLater(reactor, 3, isOffline, 'OFFLINE')
        d.addCallback(lambda ignored: reactor.stop())
        # run all system...
        reactor.run()
```

Comment: This is a very convoluted way, just to check if a server is online. Just use `import socket` and `socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 443))`, which returns a `True` or `False`.